# Did Google use a particular toolkit to create Google Keep?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, responsive-design

I really like the look and feel of Google Keep web app [keep.google.com](http://keep.google.com)
I was wondering if that's a publicly available toolkit (like bootstrap from twitter).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the implementation of a third-party website.

Comment: And so what? It's a well done website and I was wondering what technology is behind it!

Comment: "So what?"—as it is not "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"—is furthermore off-topic.

Comment: then vote to close and see if you are successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Google does have a toolkit available: https://developers.google.com/web/starter-kit/

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution myself: https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit